# Oracle sql if conditon or group by in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table-name is ProductDirection. It includes these columns.

1. operationcode
2. messagecode
3. productno
4. messages_info
5. statuscode
6. insertdate

I have a batch program and this program works max. 3 times in one day for a product.If operation success batch for a product, batch doesn't work for this product that day. So program works while it will be success and insert record fail or success.

My Records are:

```
ProductNo  StatusCode  MessagesInfo     InsertDate
---------------------------------------------------------   
1236895     0          Fail For xxx     01.01.2013 10:00:00
1236895     0          Fail For yyy     01.01.2013 15:00:00
1236895     1          Success          01.01.2013 19:00:00
1236895     0          Fail For xxx     15.01.2013 10:00:00
1236895     0          Fail For yyy     15.01.2013 15:00:00
1236895     0          Fail For zzz     15.01.2013 19:00:00
```

I want this condition. If it available success record, i want to get this record  only in one day and if all record is faliures in one day. So my records will look like this.

```
ProductNo  StatusCode MessagesInfo    InsertDate
------------------------------------------------------    
1236895     1         Success         01.01.2013 19:00:00 
1236895     0         Fail For xxx    15.01.2013 10:00:00
1236895     0         Fail For yyy    15.01.2013 15:00:00
1236895     0         Fail For zzz    15.01.2013 19:00:00
```

How can i solve?

```
SELECT *
  FROM ProductDirection p
 WHERE p.operationcode = 6
   AND p.messagecode = 2
   AND trunc(p.insertdate) BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '21.06.2013';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT *
  FROM productdirection
 WHERE (productno, TRUNC (insertdate)) IN (
                                        SELECT   productno,
                                                 TRUNC (insertdate)
                                            FROM productdirection
                                        GROUP BY productno,
                                                 TRUNC (insertdate)
                                          HAVING MAX (statuscode) = 0)
    OR statuscode = 1;
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad468/4)

Add any other where clauses as required.

Comment: thanks your answer,and sorry for my late response.I have index on productdirection table.Index include insertdate,...(from where condition columns).This query's cost is very expensive for trunc(insertdate).How can i reduce this query?.Could you offer any solution.

Comment: @engcmreng, updated the answer and the sqlfiddle. This should reduce the cost of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ProductDirection AS
(
SELECT 1236895 ProductNo, 0 StatusCode, 'Fail For xxx' MessagesInfo, TO_DATE('01.01.2013 10:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') InsertDate FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236895, 0, 'Fail For yyy', TO_DATE('01.01.2013 15:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236895, 1, 'Success',      TO_DATE('01.01.2013 19:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236895, 0, 'Fail For xxx', TO_DATE('15.01.2013 10:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236895, 0, 'Fail For yyy', TO_DATE('15.01.2013 15:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236895, 0, 'Fail For zzz', TO_DATE('15.01.2013 19:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
   FROM ProductDirection
  WHERE insertdate >=   (
                            SELECT  MAX(InsertDate)
                            FROM    ProductDirection
                            WHERE   MessagesInfo = 'Success'
                            AND     InsertDate >= TO_DATE('01.01.2013', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                        )
  ORDER BY insertdate;
/*
1236895 1   Success         2013-01-01 19:00:00
1236895 0   Fail For xxx    2013-01-15 10:00:00
1236895 0   Fail For yyy    2013-01-15 15:00:00
1236895 0   Fail For zzz    2013-01-15 19:00:00
*/
```